# Pad middle of string with 0s in mysql ORDER BY clause to respect "true" numeric order

Tags: mysql, sql, natural-sort

In my admin interface I have a listing of subdomains, which follow following logic:

```
node-k1
node-k2
node-k3
node-k4
node-k5
node-k6
node-k7
node-k8
node-k9
node-k10
node-k11
```

These are stored in mysql. I need to list them in numeric order, however since I lack leading 0s after `node-k`, it orders them like so:

```
node-k1
node-k10
node-k11
node-k2
node-k3
etc
```

There nodes have different letters, so `node-j_` would appear before `node-k_`. `ORDER BY node ASC` works fine with the letters obviously, however the numbers are an annoying issue.

Is there any way to make the ORDER BY clause put them in a right order? This is an admin only function, so performance isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number always starts at character 7, then you can cast it to an integer like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY SUBSTR(subdomain, 1, 6), CAST(SUBSTR(subdomain, 7) AS UNSIGNED)
```

This orders them first by the prefix, then by the number.

Comment: @muistooshort, oops, I didn't see that there were more than one prefix. Thanks! I updated my answer.

Comment: The number always starts at the same place, yes, however some subdomains have more letters after the number, node-k7 and node-k7-b for example. This make node-k7-b appear before node-k7, when it should be after. Other than that, this works.

Comment: @k1lljoy: You can deal with that with another `substr`.

Answer (score 0):

in your table of where the nodes were recorded, there must be a numeric field(unique) which basically refers to the order of your nodes.

ID  NodeName 
1   Node-k1 
2   Node-k2
3   Node-k3
4   Node-k10
5   Node-k11

select Nodename from table1 order by ID.

Rhian